# Create objects based in a list using dynamic SQL

Tags: postgresql

I have the following code where I have the list of channels:

```
create temporary table channels
(
name text null
);

insert into channels (name) values ('telcom');
insert into channels (name) values ('agro');
insert into channels (name) values ('sports');
insert into channels (name) values ('country');
insert into channels (name) values ('video');
```

I'm checking in the docs of Dynamic Commands in PostgreSQL (1)to find some way to create an object (in this case a view) using each element of the column of the channels table.

Something like: wv_telcom, vw_agro, vw_sports, vw_country, vw_video.

I started with the following code, but I do not know what is missing:

```
DO
$$
BEGIN
    EXECUTE format('CREATE TABLE %I AS SELECT * FROM countries', 'vw_' || variable)
    using (select names from countries);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

(1) - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN

Comment: Just to make sure it's clear, `CREATE TABLE ... AS` does not create a view; as the syntax says, it creates a table, whose *initial* contents match the query *at the time it's created*. A view would be created with `CREATE VIEW ... AS`, and would track changes to the underlying query after it was created.

Comment: Your sample data uses the table name `channels` but your code uses `countries` - which one is it? Also: do you want a `where` condition for each view restricting the number of rows?

Comment: @horse

I have a canonical view, I'll not limit the number of lines.Thx

Comment: Thanks Guys! This community it's amazing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `STRING_AGG` to generate SQL script:

```
DO
$$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE(SELECT STRING_AGG(format('CREATE VIEW %I AS SELECT * FROM countries;'
                  ,'vw_' || name), CHR(10))
           FROM channels);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=5b1280c290db16fc0d6018d0adc48b36)**

Answer (score 1):

You need a loop as you want to create a one VIEW (not table) for each value:

```
DO
$$
declare
  l_rec record;
BEGIN
    for l_rec in select names from countries
      EXECUTE format('CREATE VIEW %I AS SELECT * FROM countries WHERE name = %L', 'vw_' || l_rec.names, l_rec.names);
    end loop;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```